# intellij idea - git push window and too many commits

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Normally I use `git` from command line. I heard good things about `IDEA` and `git` integration so I started to use it for my normal tasks. Everything seems to be working fine but I encountered a strange behaviour.

Today, when I wanted to push to my remote branch on bitbucket, in push window I saw too many commits (not only those that were merged from different branch), and after commit `IDEA` said that

```
Push successful
master: pushed 16 commits.
```

It seemed strange that `IDEA` showed so many commits in push window, and when I went to repository page on bitbucket, only 3 new commits were added to `master` branch - and this was good behaviour because I merged 3 commits to `master`. Is it normal that `IDEA` shows too many commits in push window? (I assume that there should be only new commits showed there, those that were added and are going to be pushed, maybe that is not the case).

Comment: Could it have pushed commits from other branches? That option is usually defaulted to off with `git` but could have been turned on somehow. Otherwise... can you get a log anywhere of what those 16 commits were?

Comment: Is there any way to do what you want in IDEA (getting to the log what commits were displayed)?

Comment: Just saw the same thing in IDEA 13.1.2, thinking it is a bug in IntelliJ.

Comment: just came here for answer - many commits listed in IntelliJ after I previously merged in the target branch to avoid conflicts. I resorted to using GiT Gui to push just my commit from my branch. Def smells like a bug.